# Intance and prototype in one line of code

Tags: javascript, instance, prototypal-inheritance

Sample code to set the situation:

```
function Parent()
{
    //code
}

function Child()
{
    //code
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
var objChild = new Child();
```

Is it possible to write the last two lines in one?

EDIT: This came to my mind while writing this kind of code repeteadly. I'm not after a specific thing here. Just wanted to know if it possible.

Comment: and why do you want that?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but the code won't be shorter or easier to understand. You can use the comma opeator: `var objChild = Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype), new Child();`, but that's not really any improvement.

Comment: What do you really mean by "one line"?  Obviously you can put both statements in the same line, but I suspect that's not what you're after.

Comment: Yes: `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype); var objChild = new Child();`

Comment: I think you're looking for `Child.call(objChild=Object.create(Object.create(Parent.prototype)));` which has the same effects as those two lines. Hopefully it's obvious from this that they are not meant to be combined. So what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a function and pass the parent class.

```
function Parent()
{
    //code
}

function Child(parentClass)
{

  function ChildObj() {

  }

  ChildObj.prototype = Object.create(parentClass.prototype);

  return new ChildObj();
}


var objChild = Child(Parent);
```